# How can I add values from one input box to an array? and if I enter numbers in the input field, how can I get a sum of those numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I store input values from one input field to an array. And if I input numbers, then how can I get a sum of those numbers? Here's my codes.
I really appreciate some help from you guys.

My css

```
        <style>
        .item-check {
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 22px;
            height: 21px;
            cursor: pointer;
          background-image: url('https://cdn.glitch.com/72548e86-2a07-45d1-9756-a034ea6672b3%2Fincomplete.png?1495684448133');
        }

        .complete {
            background-image: url('https://cdn.glitch.com/72548e86-2a07-45d1-9756-a034ea6672b3%2Fcomplete.png?1495684439106');
        }

        .item-text {
            margin-left: 2em;
            width: 22px;
            height: 21px;
        }

        .item-remove {
          float: right;
            cursor: pointer;
          width:20px;
          height:20px;
          background-size:cover;
          background-image: url('https://cdn.glitch.com/72548e86-2a07-45d1-9756-`a034ea6672b3%2Fremove.png?1495684443965');`
        }
        </style>
```

My HTML

```
   <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My To-do List</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">
      </head>  
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <h1>My To-do List</h1>
      </header>

      <!--   Key Section of App    -->
      <form class="list-content">

        <label>
          <input type="text" class="item-input">
        </label>
        <h4 id="message"></h4>
        <ul class="shopping-list">
          <!-- <li>Sample Item</li> -->
        </ul>

        <button class="add-item">Add    Item</button>
      </form>
      <!--   Key Section of App    -->

    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

My Javascript code

// Step 1
 // This code is executed when someone clicks the "Add Item" button 
 // at the top right of the shopping-item
 // -------------------

```
   <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".add-item").on('click', function(event) {
          if ($('.item-input').val() == "") {
              alert ('Please enter some text!');
              return false;
          } else {
              var listItem = $(".item-input").val();
              var itemHtml = "<li><span class='item-check'></span><span class='item-text'>" + listItem + "</span><span class='item-remove'></span></li>";
              $(".shopping-list").append(itemHtml);

            //Remove the text the user entered from item-input   
              $('.item-input').val();
              $('.item-input').val('');

            //Count items entered
            var addedItem = $('.item-text').length;
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=("You have entered " + addedItem + " items in your list");

              event.preventDefault();
          };    
      });         

    // -------------------

    // This code is executed when someone clicks the "X" button
        $(".shopping-list").on('click', '.item-remove', function(event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).parent().remove();

        });

    // -------------------

    // This code is executed when someone clicks the checkbox in the shopping-item section
        $(".shopping-list").on('click', '.item-check', function(event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('complete');

      });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Investigate the JavaScript `push()` method. Then investigate how to iterate through the values in an array with a `for` loop.

Comment: Can you please provide output testcase?

Comment: https://codepen.io/MDeveloper/pen/bvyXMw

Comment: the link above is where you can test my app. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @Nirali can you test it on here https://jsfiddle.net/jerus1403/u80ebdyx/